# Retrieving JSON data asynchronously

Tags: android, json, asynchronous, okhttp

So, maybe someone with a little more experience with Square's OkHttp library for Android will be able to explain to me exactly what is going on. I understand the concept of the UI thread and asynchronous requests to the web, as to not clutter up the UI thread. My question is, why is my code responding before I receive the response? And how do I fix this? Here is my code, though, for security reasons, I will leave out the actual URL I am calling, but the response it should return will be posted below, as well.

```
package com.example.jeffrey.yetiagenda.ui;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.jeffrey.yetiagenda.R;
import com.example.jeffrey.yetiagenda.api.API;
import com.example.jeffrey.yetiagenda.api.User;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;


public class YetiAgenda extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = YetiAgenda.class.getSimpleName();

    public String mJSONData;

    @InjectView(R.id.usernameEdit)
    EditText mUsernameEdit;
    @InjectView(R.id.passwordEdit)
    EditText mPasswordEdit;
    @InjectView(R.id.loginButton)
    Button mLoginButton;
    @InjectView(R.id.invalidLoginText)
    TextView mInvalidLoginText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_yeti_agenda);

        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        mInvalidLoginText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //if login is successful, pass id of user to next activity to construct
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    mJSONData = null; // for debugging, read below
                    if (APICall("(removed for security reasons)")) {
                        hoorayToast();
                    } else {
                        booToast();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
                }
           }
        });
    }

    public void hoorayToast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hooray!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void booToast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Boo!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void toggleInvalidText() {
        if (mInvalidLoginText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mInvalidLoginText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            mInvalidLoginText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
   }

    public boolean APICall(String url) throws JSONException{
       // unnecessary finagling Android Studio suggested

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url).build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                // alertUserAboutError();
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    mJSONData = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG,response.body().string());
                    Log.v(TAG, mJSONData);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Signal that response was successful
                    } else {
                        // alertUserAboutError();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
                }
            }
        });
        if (mJSONData != null) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Now, the returned JSON should be as follows :

```
{"logIn":true,"id":"5","userType":"1"}
```

In conclusion, whenever I tap the button with the onClickListener(), I get the "Boo!" Toast pop-up, but almost directly afterwards, in the logcat, I see I received the JSON, which when I put a breakpoint before I set mJSONData to null, the first time I press the button nothing is there, but after I press the button a second time (and loop back through the debugger) the JSON has NOW been stored into the String, after it would normally cause my app to crash (prior to boiling it down and simply checking if it's null).

Thank you any who take their time and effort to help me understand what exactly is happening and what I can do to change it.

Comment: think about using Retrofit along with OkHttp : https://github.com/square/retrofit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply popup progress after button press. And use callback interface in your onResponse method. 
Quick draft example:

```
interface ApiCallCallback
{
void onSuccess(//RESPONSE);
void onError(String pErrorMessage);
}

public boolean APICall(String url, final ApiCallCallback pCallback)
...
@Override 
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try { 
                    mJSONData = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG,response.body().string());
                    Log.v(TAG, mJSONData);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                         pCallback.onSuccess(//RESPONSE);
                        // Signal that response was successful 
                    } else { 
                         pCallback.onError(//ERROR);
                        // alertUserAboutError(); 
                    } 
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
                }
```

//your activity or fragment should implement ApiCallCallback

```
mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try { 
                    mJSONData = null; 
                   //just run apicall to start data receive
                   APICall("(removed for security reasons)", this)) 
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught:", e);
                } 
           } 
        });
```

when APICall will invoke any interface listener, it means that data is ready and you can use it or something went wrong.

onSuccess();
OnError();

You should also check a design pattern called observer.

Comment: Not gonna lie to you, not quite understanding wholly what you mean. I haven't worked with Java interfaces yet, can you just add a quick edit to explain how this would solve the issue? How would this stop APICall from returning the null String and waiting til the change was applied?

Comment: Your implementation atm is wrong, because you're making async job, and right after you start it you're expecting a result. It's impossible because it takes time to connect / get data etc. Thats why you have to use callback interface.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Now, if it isn't an issue, could you just briefly explain how the callback interface stops this? I understand what you mean by expecting a result that hasn't been retrieved, but does the interface force the app to wait until the "callback" has been made and proven successful?

Comment: I tried implementing the callback function and it didn't change when APICall concluded or when the information was stored in mJSONData, the app still trucked ahead and proceeded to give me my booToast() test notification (due to mJSONData being null from lack of a response yet) and then the logcat showed that the JSON was indeed stored and logged at the same time (after the method APICall had finished).